# Как с помощью стилей понизить непрозрачность у placeholder?

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Допустим, у нас есть `<input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>`. Отображается поле с базовой надписью в нём, мне нужно в самом поле сделать эту надпись чуть-чуть прозрачной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Стилизуем HTML5 Placeholder на CSS](http://kobzarev.com/makeup/html5-placeholder-styling-with-css.html)

```
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder  { opacity: 0.5; -moz-opacity: 0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=5); }
input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder { opacity: 0.5; -moz-opacity: 0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=5); }
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/fBnMR/).

Comment: filter:alpha(opacity=50) что бы одинаково было.
[Вот хорошая статья про прозрачность][1]


  [1]: http://www.tigir.com/opacity.htm

Answer (score 1):

[@angers777](/users/7766/angers777) сделайте как @сaravaneer но применяйте rgba вместо opacity (у меня была проблема с ним)